# Ring endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

What are the ring endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$? I know that for just $\mathbb{Q}$ alone, then answer is simply $\mathbb{Q}$, but what happens in this case?

Comment: Endomorphisms as what structure? Ordered set? Additive group? Ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only idempotent elements of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ other than $0$ and $1$ are  $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Thus a ring endomorphism must either fix or exchange these two elements. From there it shouldn't be too difficult to prove that there are exactly two ring endomorphisms - the identity and the one that exchanges the coordinates.

Comment: What about scaling?

Comment: No, that won't work. For example, $f(x) = 2x$ is an endomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ viewed as an Abelian group, but not as a ring.